# Android Studio build error - compileDebugJavaWithJavac task (current target it 1.8) and kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin task (current target is 18)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

I recently encountered a build error in Android Studio while working on a new project. The error message I received is as follows:

```
    Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
    > 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task     
    (current target is 18) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
```

This issue arose after I integrated Hilt support into my project. For context, I'm currently using "Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1" and "Hedgehog 2023.1.1 Beta 4" versions.

Interestingly, when I remove Hilt from the project, everything compiles and runs smoothly without any errors. This leads me to believe that the integration of Hilt might be the root cause of the problem.

To provide a clearer picture, here's the content of my build.gradle file:

```
    plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
    }

    android {
    namespace = "de.test"
    compileSdk = 34

    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(18)
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "de.test"
        minSdk = 28
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 2
        versionName = "2.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "18"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
    }

    dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.09.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.1")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.09.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.5.1")

    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")

    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.48")
    }

    kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
    }
```

i use gradle 8.1.1 and OpenJDK jdk-18.0.2

nothing helps

It can't be the case that a completely new project causes such problems. It seems to be related to kotlin kapt activation at the beginning.

id("kotlin-kapt")

Comment: How about setting jvmTarget =1.8?

Comment: Don't forget to put 1.8 inside quotes

Comment: No, that doesn't help.

Comment: I mixed up the JDK versions.

Java 1.8 <> 18

I have now completely switched to java 17, as suggested for Android Target 43.
Problem solved.